# I keep getting this error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

The link for my code is at : https://github.com/justgoof9/IMDB/blob/master/src/App.js

The movieRatings i'm trying to render are these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DYlY.png

In the lines 99-104, is where I try to render the movieRatings but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Please don't put up links to images or what not of your code, please include it as formatted text in your post. As far as the error you are getting, it means that some variable that you are calling .map() on is undefined.

Comment: Your render method should be written in a way that works regardless of the data being already loaded or not. Which means you need to either initialize `this.state.newMovieParsed.movieRatings` to `[]` or use conditional rendering: `{ this.state.newMovieParsed.movieRatings && this.state.newMovieParsed.movieRatings.map(...) }` (also, are you having trouble interpreting this very clear error message? because if so, it's technically way too early to post on stack overflow)

Comment: Thank you very much the [] worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your data with arrays, like below:

```
newMovieParsed : {
    movieTitle: '',
    moviePosters: [],
    moviePlot: '',
    movieGenre: '',
    movieBoxOffice: '',
    movieRatings: [],
    movieActors: [],
    imdbId:''
}
```

That's also better to understand at a first glance which type of data you need for your props.